# Android combine Animations in one transformation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm currently trying to make an Animation rotating around the y axis + scaling + rotating at the same time.

The rotation animation is based on [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html). Currently I have all the animations in an AnimationSet, which works but is quite slow. So I thought I could combine all three animations in the rotate animation, since I already have an applyTransformation there. So I checked the Android source for ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation and it all seemed very simple. But it doesn't work.

So now the question: is that even possible? And if yes: What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I'm getting closer! The translation and rotation work now. Only the scaling is missing. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((toDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    float sx = 1.0f;
    float sy = 1.0f;

    if (scaleFromX != 1.0f || scaleToX != 1.0f) {
        sx = scaleFromX + ((scaleToX - scaleFromX) * interpolatedTime);
    }
    if (scaleFromY != 1.0f || scaleToY != 1.0f) {
        sy = scaleFromY + ((scaleToY - scaleFromY) * interpolatedTime);
    }

    float dx = fromDeltaX;
    float dy = fromDeltaY;
    if (fromDeltaX != toDeltaX) {
        dx = fromDeltaX + ((toDeltaX - fromDeltaX) * interpolatedTime);
    }
    if (fromDeltaY != toDeltaY) {
        dy = fromDeltaY + ((toDeltaY - fromDeltaY) * interpolatedTime);
    }

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    matrix.setTranslate(dx, dy);
    matrix.setScale(sx, sy, pivotX, pivotY);

    camera.save();
    if (reverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f - interpolatedTime);
    }
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX + dx, centerY + dy);

}
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't really help me. I know how to use a custom animation, but I don't know how I can combine those three animations in one (if that's even possible)

Comment: @MariaNeumayer there are also Rotate3dAnimation in `Api-Demos` are you check it ?>

Comment: yes. i've linked in in my question. again: the problem is NOT using those animations - they work fine if I use them in an AnimationSet, but slow, so I'd like to combine them in one.